# MahApps DateTimePicker 24 hour time format

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am using the **DateTimePicker** control of **MahApps**. By default, it's showing time in 12 hours format. But I need the **24 hours** format. Any idea how to achieve that?

```xaml
<controls:DateTimePicker 
    SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDateTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
    SelectedTimeFormat="Short" 
    SelectedDateFormat="Short"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 24 Hour format depend on the Cultural Properties. For example, if you were to set the cultural to "en-In" or "cs-CZ", both having default 24 hour format, it would not show the AM/PM designator.

```
<Controls:DateTimePicker 
    SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDateTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
    Culture="en-In"
    SelectedTimeFormat="Short" 
    SelectedDateFormat="Short"/>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: the culture `en-In` worked for me. culture `cs-CZ` changes the calender language.